# Calculate pay periods based on 14 day pay period - PHP/SQL

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, modx

I have a database that collects user input on their time in/out. I am collecting this information like so:

```
user_id     clock_in    clock_out
612         1383710400  1383728400
612         1384315200  1384333200
508         1383710400  1383738400
```

While looping, I calculate the hours of each object like so:
`$total=(($e->clock_out-$e->clock_in)/60/60);`

**Where I am stuck**
I'm a bit stuck on how to group them into pay periods. I know that there are 26 pay periods in a year. I also know our starting pay period for this year was `01.13.14 - 01.26.14`.

**What I have tried:**
I thought to try just gathering the week of the year `date('W',$e->clock_in)` while looping through the database results but I am not sure how to group them.

**Question:** 
Is grouping/sorting possible while looping during a `foreach`? Do you suggest a different approach on grouping/sorting the data into pay periods?

Please let me know if more code is needed, etc. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming those are standard Unix timestamps, you can trivially extract/mangle dates any way you want. If your workweek corresponds to a standard calendar week, it's even easier:

```
SELECT user_id, clock_in-clock_out
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(clock_in))
```

This will just group by single weeks, but this is just to give you a general idea.

MySQL has a very wide variety of date/time functions that can be used for this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

Comment: Great link, I find that entire page helpful. So you suspect that grouping during the extraction is better than doing after?

Comment: That depends on your grouping rules and how your work week maps to calendar weeks. If the sql gets too ugly, you'd be better off doing it in PHP. Plus there's edge cases like a payperiod that crosses a year boundary. You could start in week-of-year 52 and end in week-of-year 1, for a -51 weeks worked.

Comment: Ah yes, I see your point, thanks for that. I am testing this now to see how feasible it is since our work week does map to calendar weeks well (mon-sun and this correlates with the `date('W')` well).